# twisted SMTP server limit incoming email message size

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, smtp, twisted

This is the very basic code that I am using to create an SMTP server using twisted:

```py
from email.Header import Header
from twisted.internet import protocol, defer, reactor
from twisted.mail import smtp
from zope.interface import implements


class ConsoleMessageDelivery(object):
    implements(smtp.IMessageDelivery)

    def receivedHeader(self, helo, origin, recipients):
        myHostname, clientIP = helo
        headerValue = "by %s from %s with ESMTP ; %s" % (myHostname,
                                                         clientIP,
                                                         smtp.rfc822date())
        return "Received: %s" % Header(headerValue)

    def validateFrom(self, helo, origin):
        # All addresses are accepted
        return origin

    def validateTo(self, user):
        # Only messages directed to the "console@domain" user are accepted.
        if user.dest.local == "console":
            return lambda: ConsoleMessage()
        raise smtp.SMTPBadRcpt(user)


class ConsoleMessage(object):
    implements(smtp.IMessage)

    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)

    def eomReceived(self):
        print "New message received:"
        print "\n".join(self.lines)
        self.lines = None
        return defer.succeed(None)

    def connectionLost(self):
        # There was an error, throw away the stored lines
        self.lines = None


class LocalSMTPFactory(smtp.SMTPFactory):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        smtpProtocol = smtp.ESMTP()
        smtpProtocol.delivery = ConsoleMessageDelivery()
        return smtpProtocol

reactor.listenTCP(2025, LocalSMTPFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I can receive emails but if I would like to reject incoming message with size of  1MB or more,  how could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `ConsoleMessage.lineReceived` is called with each line of the message.  Each line has a size (similar to its length, no doubt).  You can tally the size of all the lines as they are received and take action based on the result.

Additionally, you could explore the `SIZE` ESMTP extension which allows the server to declare the maximum message size which will be accepted.  This does not *replace* checking in the code handling message lines since there's no guarantee a client will respect the declared maximum but in the case of a smart, cooperating client it will save some pointless data transfer.

`SIZE` is a simple enough extension that you can probably add it to Twisted's ESMTP server by subclassing `twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTP` and overriding the `extensions` method to add it.

Comment: Any idea of how I could use/declare the extensions?

Comment: I am trying to define the SIZE extension with with ``def extensions(self): ext = {'SIZE': 1048576} return ext`` but got an TypeError because of --> r.append('%s %s' % (c, ' '.join(v))) what is the proper way to add extensions so that I can get something like '250-SIZE 1048576'

Comment: Maybe you can think of a data structure which, when `" ".join(it)` is applied to it, will produce `"1048576"`?

Comment: I end using ext['SIZE'] = ['1048576'], one last questions, does the '-' after the 250 isn't required also for extensions?

Comment: The - is general SMTP syntax having to do with response termination.